# Having trouble accessing the API via data.nba.net

Tags: ios, xcode11, swift5

I have the Url saved in the info.plist as such:
BASE_URL <-> String <-> $(BASE_URL)

and in my project's Build Settings, I added a user-defined setting as such:
BASE_URL            http://data.nba.net

After setting this up, when I try to get the website into the url variable, the variable returns "". As I debug the issue, I don't see the website stored under that variable.

I am new to Swift and still learning so any comments on the way I have setup my structs will be appreciated as well.

```
import UIKit

struct sports_content: Decodable {
    let sports_meta_expanded: sports_meta
    let teams_expanded: teams
}

struct sports_meta: Decodable {
    let date_time: String?
    let season_meta_list: season_meta
}

struct season_meta: Decodable {
    let calendar_date: Date
    let season_year: Int?
    let stats_season_year: Int?
    let stats_season_id: Int?
    let stats_season_stage: Int?
    let roster_season_year: Int?
    let schedule_season_year: Int?
    let standings_season_year: Int?
    let season_id: Int?
    let display_year: String
    let display_season: String
    let season_stage: Int?
}

struct next: Decodable {
    let url: String
}

struct teams: Decodable {
    let season_year: year
    let team_data: [team]
}

struct year: Decodable {
    let season_year: Int?
}

struct team: Decodable {
    let is_nba_team: Bool
    let team_name: String
    let team_nickname: String
    let team_code: String
    let team_abbrev: String
    let city: String
    let state: String
    let team_short_name: String
    let team_id: Int?
    let conference: String
    let division_id: String
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        let url = Bundle.main.infoDictionary?["BASE_URL"] as? String ?? ""

        guard let convertedURL = URL(string: url) else {
            return
        }

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: convertedURL) { (data, response, error) in
        guard let data = data else {
            return
        }
        do{
            let dataSet = try JSONDecoder().decode(sports_content.self, from: data)
            print(dataSet)
        } catch {
            print("JSONSerialization error:", error)
        }
        }.resume()
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

A build setting is used at build / compile time and not necessarily at run time.

To get your URL into the infoDictionary, you need to add it to the Info.plist file. Double click on your Info.plist to get the view open in your Xcode, then click "Add Value" under the Editor menu, then you can add `BASE_URL` as the key and your URL as the value.

[image: add item to Info.plist]

Try using $(BASE_URL) as the value in your Info.plist and see if your build setting gets added in at build time.  :)

Comment: Hey Michael,

Thank You - I tried that and in my code, the url variable does not contain the link. Moreover as I put the breakpoint on the line
 guard let convertedURL = URL(string: url) else

this is the error I get - 
expression produced error: error: Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x7fbccd54e7b0).

How do I take care of this?